# ubuntu shuts down for no reason

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, live-cd

Up until 2 days ago Ubuntu 12.04 was going simply great, then the update manager prompted for some updates and I continued as usual.

After that I  continued to use the computer for few more hours then I restarted it but seems dead. I unplugged the power cable, waited about 30 sec and restarted, and it does work, however with my great surprise once it reaches the Grub screen and I select the OS I want (I have only Ubuntu 12.04 on this system) the computer shuts down and I am unable to restart it. I have to unplug the power cable and wait a few seconds until I can restart it.

If I choose the second option, it does not shutdown; but after a zillion of lines it takes me to a new window where I can chose what option i want. I tried to check the file system and it was ok; if i click "repair broken package" and I agree to upgrade i get numerous lines says "error unable to fetch....". If I chose low graphic mode I am taken to a second window but whatever is the option that I chose I get a blank screen which stays there for several minutes, with a dash blinking on the top left corner of the monitor but nothing happens.

I am currently working with a live CD but and I wonder what would be the best way to proceed. Can I fix it from the live cd? how?

Comment: I can't attach the log to this thread, i get an error msg "you have to wait 8 hours before posting"

If I try to edit my question it says "too long"

Ok found a way to show the log: I created a link in google docs: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CzFUVDoXVeSyJCvN7znaCit47FL1C_2dkkRWZE6hBBA/edit?usp=sharing           what do you guys think? is it possible to restore the system?  I have files that I need to recover and eventually after that if nothing works i can reinstall the OS.

Comment: Anybody willing to share their thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you have setup your filesystem, you should fairly easily be able to re-install ubuntu.

If this isn't an option (ie. you have things in your home drive that will have to be deleted in order to reinstall due to a `/` and `/home` being on the same drive.)

if you upload your apt `history.log`, found at `/var/log/apt/history.log`, we can have a look through what you have installed in the past couple of days.

Do you remember what was installed that broke the system?
If the live cd is working, then it doesn't sound like a hardware problem, and maybe it's a config error of some kind.